# Make Ember Route password protected

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to prompt the user with a modal that requires the confirmation of his/her password, before the transition to a given route (in this case my `App.UserSettingsRoute`). I've got this to work generally (I'm opening the modal and aborting the transition in the `beforeModel` hook, and resume the transition when the password is confirmed), but I'm facing the following problem:

When the user enters the route directly (by typing in the URL in the address bar directly or by refreshing the browser while in the route), I cannot open the modal (I get an error) because I have not yet entered any route yet - this is the first route being entered in the application. My question: How can I detect that the current route I am entering is the first one? Alternatively, is there a better approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this method from webcloud:

http://webcloud.github.io/blog/2014/04/07/emberjs-authentication-the-right-way-javascript-version/

You can also use the:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function(transition, queryParams){
        // Do auth here...
    }
});
```

This route is always hit first no matter what route in your app the visitor directly types in.